# Dynamic Form from Server Response

Tags: angular, forms, http

i created a DynamicForm Project with this Tutorial and it works fine.

https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da

Now I want to use a server that initially provides the form state and reacts to changes in the form.

Therefore I request the form inital from the server and changed the AppComponent like this.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent) form: DynamicFormComponent;
  regConfig: FieldConfig[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getForm();
  }

  valueChange(value) {
    this.getForm(value.name);
  }

  getForm(name?) {
    let myParams = new HttpParams().set('lang', 'de');
    if (!!name) {
      myParams = myParams.set('name', name);
    }
    this.http.get('http://10.9.99.128:8080', {params: myParams})
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.regConfig = value['formControls'];
      });
  }
}
```

and the DynamicFormComponent to this:

```
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() fields: FieldConfig[] = [];
  @Output() submit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({});

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.form = this.createControl();
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      this.submit.emit(value);
    });
  }
}
```

Now I have the problem that after entering a value, I send the request to the server, which responds with a new form representation. But since it is a completely new form, the current field will miss its focus. Especially for input fields, you have to click into the field again after each letter.

How do I create a dynamic form where the server determines which fields are displayed and which are not depending on the input values?

Best regards